# Android emulator. Its posible сomplete removal com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox?

Tags: android, android-emulator

AVD Manager installs pure android. Most of the components do nothing, except that they flood a huge amount of unnecessary information into the logs.The champion among them is `com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox`. It writes a lot of information to the `Logcat` and `jobscheduler` (adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler). Can i somehow remove this component, which is essentially useless and only floods?

Answer (score 0):

For grins I tried:

```
adb shell 
su
pm uninstall package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
```

The system rebooted itself and the package was there again. So no, I don't think it's possible to remove it.

What you can do in Android Studio is, in the Logcat pane, choose `Show only selected application` (usually on the far right of the header). Then choose your app in the box to the right of the machine selector. That will show only your app in the logcat.

Comment: Thanks. In Logcat, you can indeed switch modes and sort using regular expressions, but after several restarts of the application, the logs are often displayed incorrectly.